# Are the rows locked in order in a SELECT ... ORDER BY ... FOR UPDATE statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, database-deadlocks

This question can be considered as a follow-up on my comment on [Can two concurrent but identical DELETE statements cause a deadlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51969812/can-two-concurrent-but-identical-delete-statements-cause-a-deadlock#comment90893165_51969812).

I am wondering if the rows are locked in ascending `my_status` order in the following statement:

```
SELECT 1 FROM my_table ORDER BY my_status FOR UPDATE;
```

There is an interesting remark on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-select.html which says:

> It is possible for a `SELECT` command running at the `READ COMMITTED` transaction isolation level and using `ORDER BY` and a locking clause to return rows out of order. This is because `ORDER BY` is applied first. The command sorts the result, but might then block trying to obtain a lock on one or more of the rows. Once the `SELECT` unblocks, some of the ordering column values might have been modified, leading to those rows appearing to be out of order (though they are in order in terms of the original column values). This can be worked around at need by placing the `FOR UPDATE`/`SHARE` clause in a sub-query, for example
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable FOR UPDATE) ss ORDER BY column1;
> ```

I am not sure if that answers my question. All this says is that `ORDER BY` is applied first and that you need to put the `FOR UPDATE` in a subquery to work around the side effect that the actual output order might differ if values of the order column(s) have been changed in the meantime.  In other words, putting `FOR UPDATE` in a subquery ensures that locking happens before ordering.

But this does not really tell us if the rows are actually locked in the order determined by the `ORDER BY` clause?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows are locked in the order of the `ORDER BY` clause **as it was when the table was scanned**.

The query is executed and the rows ordered, then PostgreSQL locks the rows in order. Essentially, `ORDER BY` happens before `FOR UPDATE`.

Now it can happen that **locking a row blocks** because of locks held by concurrent transactions. If that happens, and we are at the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level, PostgreSQL **waits** until it can get the lock and **then fetches the current version** of the row, which it locks.

If the concurrent transaction modified the columns which define the ordering, the final result will not be in the order defined by `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Reading [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311951/should-select-for-update-always-contain-order-by) (not specific to Postgres), it seems like `ORDER BY` does not guarantee the access order. Maybe this doesn't apply to Postgres, and `ORDER BY` is indeed the right way to prevent a deadlock from `SELECT FOR UPDATE`?

Comment: @payne Look at `EXPLAIN` output to see the order of execution. That will show you if sorting happens before the rows are locked or not.